# Floating div with scroll ability

Tags: jquery

I have been looking for a floating div/menu that will not only float like the example below

http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

but when the floater div/menu height exceeds that of the view port allow you to use the main scroll bars to view the parts of the menu that are above or below the view port.

but once it reaches the end of the floater div/menu it will lock on to the top or the bottom depending on which direction you are scrolling.

every floating div always seem to lock to the top and this works great if you have a fixed height that will not grow.

To see how the floating div example above fails, using firebug or dev tools make the height of the div larger then the view port, it will fail to work.  Or just resize the window so its shorter then the height of the floating div, you will see it stops following you as you scroll down the long page.

This is an issue beacuse I have a dynamic option menu that expands contracts like istockphoto's options, you can see it below.

http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/boxer/source/

you can see how it can outgrow the view port. I want it to float but allow you to scroll up or down until you reach the upper or lower bounds of the menu and then stick to either the top or bottom depending on the direction you are scrolling.

I hope that makes sense, I have been working on a floater that monitors the scroll position and direction you are scrolling and then using offset height and bottom adjusts the margin height of the element on scroll to give the appearance its floating... blah

it just seems too much going on for something that seems to be simple enough.

does anyone know of a plugin to make a floating div scroll with the main window if the div is taller then the view port height?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, if you can use jQuery UI, they support a dialog: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Then you can set min-height, min-width, to allow the box to span as large as the content, or by you can use the height/width settings to only allow a certain size, then the overflow:auto to allow for scroll bars.